# How to filter a value in json field type on Postgres 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.2

My json field data is like this:

```
{"active":true,"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","settings":{"secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expires":"2019-12-16 01:11:23"},"plan":"Sample"}
```

Then I tried to query the field like this:

```
select * from integrations.accounts where field -> 'id' = 'xxxxxx';
```

But it gives me an error of:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json -> unknown

I found that the arrow operator (`->`) is [not supported in version 9.2:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> Unsupported versions: 9.3 / 9.2

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Neither 9.2 nor 9.2 are supported any more. Why not simply upgrade to the current version and profit from all the new JSON features that were added in the last 7 years.

Answer (score 4):

You would need the [**`->>`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) instead:

```
select * from integrations.accounts where field ->> 'id' = 'xxxxxx';
```

But these operators were added with Postgres 9.3. Postgres 9.2 is just too old (and unsupported by now). It had barely more than the data type `json` itself. There seems to be a third-party extension "Json Enhancements for PostgreSQL 9.2":

- https://clarkdave.net/2013/06/adding-json-enhancements-to-postgresql-9-2/
- https://www.pgxn.org/dist/json_enhancements/doc/json_enhancements.html#Json.Enhancements.for.PostgreSQL.9.2

But I have never tried it and would ***much*** rather upgrade to a current, supported version of Postgres instead. See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: the ->> operator is not exist